# Use MutableStateFlow as Hot stream, Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I am migrating from LiveData to Flow and faced the following problem:

I have a flow in viewModel

```
class MyViewModel() : ViewModel() {
   val state = MutableStateFlow<Boolean>(false)
}

class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
        viewModel.loginPresenterState.startVerifyFragmentEvent.collectLatest {
            Log.d("Nurs", "loginPresenterState $it")
            if (it)
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment)
        }
    }
}
```

}

when this flow is triggered , My FirstFragment navigates to another fragment "B".
But when I press back button, the `state` triggers one more time, and instead of navigating to FirstFragment, I am coming back to "B".  I suppose this behavior is because Flow is Cold. How to manage it be called only once?

Comment: See documentation: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the states remain same and when you came back it re-observes state and navigates. Check this article and use the EventWrapper that mentioned in the article. He used livedata but same logic applies for stateflow too. [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150)